# MacOS two nodes on same test network. "datadir already used by another process"

Tags: go-ethereum, bootnodes, macos

I am very new so thanks for the help, On MacOs I'm trying to attache two nodes to a private network, one node is succesfully launched to an existing bootnode. Everything I've read says to launch the second in a new terminal windo but it returns "fatal error lanching protocol stack: datadir already used by another process."

Am I missing a permission that allows me to run geth in multiple terminal windows on MacOs?

I think this

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Geth? Seems like you are using the same datadir for both instances.

```
geth --port 30303 --datadir ~/.ethA
geth --port 30304 --datadir ~/.ethB
```

You can check out the command option [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/command-line-options).

Comment: It's should be the same --datadir unless I'm missing something. I follow the directions I've been given to start separate folders for each node.

Comment: datadir is the database entry for your nodes so it is not really related to the folder directory. I am not 100% sure if there is a way to allow two nodes to share the same directory. But this should be a quick fix for this error message.